# Compare keys value on two list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, compare

I'm trying to compare the contents of a dictionary from 2 lists of dict, I have data like this

```py
data1 = [
    {
        "name": "MoreDependentsInd",
        "description": "Form 1040-SP Indicator",
        "data_type": "CheckboxType",
        "xpath": "",
    },
    {
        "name": "DependentFirstNm",
        "description": "Form 1040-SR Indicator",
        "data_type": "PersonNameControlType",
        "xpath": "",
    },
]

data2 = [
    {
        "id": 29,
        "kind": "IN",
        "container": 1,
        "content": "null",
        "uid": "IRS 1040-DependentDetail",
        "title": "DependentDetail",
        "display_name": "null",
        "description": "null",
        "extra_info": {
            "kind": "null",
            "include": {
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonFirstNameType",
                        "name": "DependentFirstNm",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent First Name",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonLastNameType",
                        "name": "DependentLastNm",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Last Name",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonNameControlType",
                        "name": "DependentNameControlTxt",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Name Control",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "null",
                        "name": "IdentityProtectionPIN",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent/Qualifying Child Identity Protection PIN",
                                "line_number": "(2)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": {"rule": "null"},
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "null",
                        "name": "DependentRelationshipCd",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Relationship Code",
                                "line_number": "(3)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": {
                            "rule": {
                                "kind": "TextType",
                                "enumeration": [
                                    "SON",
                                    "DAUGHTER",
                                    "STEPCHILD",
                                    "FOSTER CHILD",
                                    "BROTHER",
                                    "SISTER",
                                    "STEPBROTHER",
                                    "STEPSISTER",
                                    "HALF BROTHER",
                                    "HALF SISTER",
                                    "GRANDCHILD",
                                    "NIECE",
                                    "NEPHEW",
                                    "PARENT",
                                    "GRANDPARENT",
                                    "AUNT",
                                    "UNCLE",
                                    "OTHER",
                                    "NONE",
                                ],
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonFirstNameType",
                        "name": "DependentFirstNm",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent First Name",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonLastNameType",
                        "name": "DependentLastNm",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Last Name",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonNameControlType",
                        "name": "DependentNameControlTxt",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Name Control",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "null",
                        "name": "IdentityProtectionPIN",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent/Qualifying Child Identity Protection PIN",
                                "line_number": "(2)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": {"rule": "null"},
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "null",
                        "name": "DependentRelationshipCd",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Relationship Code",
                                "line_number": "(3)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": {
                            "rule": {
                                "kind": "TextType",
                                "enumeration": [
                                    "SON",
                                    "DAUGHTER",
                                    "STEPCHILD",
                                    "FOSTER CHILD",
                                    "BROTHER",
                                    "SISTER",
                                    "STEPBROTHER",
                                    "STEPSISTER",
                                    "HALF BROTHER",
                                    "HALF SISTER",
                                    "GRANDCHILD",
                                    "NIECE",
                                    "NEPHEW",
                                    "PARENT",
                                    "GRANDPARENT",
                                    "AUNT",
                                    "UNCLE",
                                    "OTHER",
                                    "NONE",
                                ],
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonFirstNameType",
                        "name": "DependentFirstNm",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent First Name",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonLastNameType",
                        "name": "DependentLastNm",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Last Name",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "PersonNameControlType",
                        "name": "DependentNameControlTxt",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Name Control",
                                "line_number": "(1)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": "null",
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "null",
                        "name": "IdentityProtectionPIN",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent/Qualifying Child Identity Protection PIN",
                                "line_number": "(2)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": {"rule": "null"},
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "null",
                        "name": "DependentRelationshipCd",
                        "annotation": {
                            "documentation": {
                                "description": "Dependent Relationship Code",
                                "line_number": "(3)",
                            }
                        },
                        "restriction": {
                            "rule": {
                                "kind": "TextType",
                                "enumeration": [
                                    "SON",
                                    "DAUGHTER",
                                    "STEPCHILD",
                                    "FOSTER CHILD",
                                    "BROTHER",
                                    "SISTER",
                                    "STEPBROTHER",
                                    "STEPSISTER",
                                    "HALF BROTHER",
                                    "HALF SISTER",
                                    "GRANDCHILD",
                                    "NIECE",
                                    "NEPHEW",
                                    "PARENT",
                                    "GRANDPARENT",
                                    "AUNT",
                                    "UNCLE",
                                    "OTHER",
                                    "NONE",
                                ],
                            }
                        },
                    },
                ],
                "reference": "null",
            },
            "annotation": "null",
            "max_occurs": "100",
            "min_occurs": "0",
            "restriction": "null",
        },
        "instruction": "null",
        "created_at": "2022-04-26T09:53:36.426118Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-26T09:53:36.426203Z",
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "kind": "IN",
        "container": 1,
        "content": "null",
        "uid": "IRS 1040-MoreDependentsInd",
        "title": "MoreDependentsInd",
        "display_name": "null",
        "description": "null",
        "extra_info": {
            "kind": "CheckboxType",
            "include": "null",
            "annotation": {
                "documentation": {
                    "description": "More Dependents Indicator",
                    "line_number": "null",
                }
            },
            "max_occurs": "null",
            "min_occurs": "0",
            "restriction": "null",
        },
        "instruction": "null",
        "created_at": "2022-04-26T09:53:36.427552Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-26T09:53:36.427647Z",
    },
]
```

```py
for i in data1:
    for j in data2:
        if i["name"] == j["title"]:
            print("success")
```

the result is a success, but in my code, there is a deficiency, if it processes a lot of data then the performance will feel slow, how to fix it? and what if the value such as the data type is in a key that we don't know is located?

for example, I search value `data_type` from `data1` I compare it with `CheckboxType`

```py
"extra_info": {
            "kind": "CheckboxType",
            "include": "null",
            "annotation": {
                "documentation": {
                    "description": "More Dependents Indicator",
                    "line_number": "null",
                }
            },
```

from `data2` on index 1 `data2[1]` but the value `CheckboxType` is also exist in another key on `data2` in another index

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the test in O(n) instead of O(n^2) by building sets of `name` and `title` (which is O(n)) and then taking their intersection (which is also O(n) now that they're sets):

```
>>> {i["name"] for i in data1} & {i["title"] for i in data2}
{'MoreDependentsInd'}
```

Non-empty sets are truthy so you can use this in a conditional if you don't care about what the intersection is:

```
>>> if {i["name"] for i in data1} & {i["title"] for i in data2}:
...     print("success")
...
success
```

If you want to look at all string values without having to know that `name` and `title` are the intersecting keys, use another generator expression to put all string values into the two sets:

```
>>> {v for i in data1 for v in i.values() if isinstance(v, str)} & {v for i in data2 for v in i.values() if isinstance(v, str)}
{'MoreDependentsInd'}
```

Comment: If you want to get all the strings in all the sub-dictionaries etc, flatten the dictionaries and put the resulting values in the sets -- that's a question in itself so I didn't cover it in my answer, but if you google "flatten python dictionaries" you'll find that it's a very well-worn path.

Comment: what if you want to find the key based on the value from the dictionary?

Comment: Based on what value?